# AutoIt - DllOpen() not opening a present .dll file i.e. it is returning -1

Tags: autoit

I'm attempting to open a .dll file which is present in my filepath through an AutoIt program I have converted to an exe using Aut2Exe.

When I convert the program to a .exe file, I'm unable to open file as DllOpen() returns a -1 but when I run it SciTE Script Editor it works fine i.e. it is is able to open the .dll file.

The manner in which I've used the DllOpen can be found on this [link](https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/5e99529f70b72207dde5) i.e. GistHub specifically in function _CommSetPort.

Any ideas as to why the function DllOpen when the program is a .exe  file would be returning -1 as its return value when clearly the .dll fine it is asked to open is available.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The working directory probably changed. Is the dll kept either on a PATH directory or in the same directory as the exe?

Comment: @Matt: the .dll file is in the same directory as the .exe file.

Comment: You could provide the DLL with `FileInstall(...)` in the `@TempDir` and open it from there... - will this work?

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer: thanks for the reply. I've provided the File through function FileInstall() as indicated in line 62 here https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/53cb82d6cc338243f6be with no success either by passing the arguments are follows: FileInstall("commg.dll", "commg.dll", 1) or by adding the directory path files to 1st argument and leaving the second argument with a trailing backslash.

Comment: You need to have a plain String for the first argument. Like `FileInstall(".\commg.dll", @TempDir & "\commg.dll")` if you want to use the dll-file being located in the same directory as the au3-script and then use `$dll = DllOpen(@TempDir & "\commg.dll")`. You must get a return value of 1 from `FileInstall(...)`.

Comment: Hi JohannesThomasMeyer: Thanks for the reply. I executed the FileInstall() as follows $x = FileInstall("commg.dll", @TempDir & "commg.dll", 1) and the DllOpen() as follows $hDll = DllOpen(@TempDir & $DLLNAME). When I run the program in the SciTE Script Editor the result of $x = 1 and the result of $hDll = 1 which means successful outcomes from both functions. When I convert the script to a .exe and run it the results are as follows $x = 0 which means it failed to install the file and $hDll = -1 meaning it didn't open the file. I'm baffled as to why this would be happening.

Comment: Hi JohannesThomasMeyer: I forgot toi mention above $DLLNAME is the file name. I declared this as follows Global $DLLNAME = "commg.dll" as seen here https://gist.github.com/AMonari1/5e99529f70b72207dde5

Answer (score 0):

When you Compile exe , be sure that you use option:
Add required  Constants*.au3 to your script

Mostly that is reason why  some  code works in SciTe  and not working as exe.

regards